# google profile currentLocation

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to get the `currentLocation` from a google profile once I have gone through auth. In the auth i request the scope as:

```
scope=["profile", "email"]
```

I found the following post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974426/google-api-get-profiles-currentlocation)

But it doesn't really answer the question. I  can get the email and basic information from the following call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=
```

But I'm unable to find the correct documentation and REST url for retrieving the current location. I'm finding the google documentation really $hit and annoying. Can anyone direct me to resources to get this or tell me how to retrieve information like the location from a google profile?

Comment: you can find the things like where the user have lived before in life..

Comment: I don't believe that `currentLocation` is available through the API. See [Field 'currentLocation' is not provided in API result](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=620)